# Envio de datos de session por POST

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, ejs

Necesito pasar dos parametros. El DNI (con el cual el usuario se registro y el id del candidato al que votó.

La ruta buscada seria como por ejemplo:

http://localhost:3000/api/DNI/ID-CANDIDATO

---

Acá genere el formulario que enviara estos dos datos. 
Probe enviando el ID del candidato y anda perfecto. Me faltaria poder enviar el parametro DNI con el cual se logueo el usuario. Tenia pensado capturarlo de los datos de la sesion pero no se de que forma y si es la mas conveniente.

```
                <% locals.candidatos.forEach((item) => { %>

                    <li class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="cnt-block equal-hight" style="height: 349px;">
                            <img class="img img-fluid d-block mx-auto rounded img-thumbnail" src="<%= item.foto %>">
                            <h3>
                                <%= item.nombreApellido %>
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                <%= item.partido %>
                            </p>

                            <form id="formulario" action="/api/votapi/<%= item._id %>" method="POST">
                                <ul class="follow-us clearfix">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase mb-2 rounded-pill shadow-sm" type="text">VOTAR</button>
                                </ul>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <% }); %>

                        </form>
```

---

Desde la API lo quiero trabajar de esta manera ya que luego de recibir los datos del POST, por un lado incremento en 1 el voto al candidato elegido y por el otro modifico el booleano (por defecto en false) para convertirlo en true. Y asi usarlo para chequear si X usuario ya votó.

```
<!-- API -->
routerApi.post('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.id) {
        console.log(req.params.user.id);
        Candidato.update({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { votos: 1 } }, { safe: true },
            function(err, response) {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send(error);
                if (response) {
                    User.updateOne({ dni: req.session.user.dni }, { $set: { voto: true } }, { safe: true },
                        function(err, response) {
                            if (err) return res.status(500).send(error);
                            if (response) {
                                res.status(200).redirect('/resultados');
                                console.log('Voto exitoso!')
                            }

                        });
                } else {
                    res.status(500).send(new Error("No se pudo votar"));

                }
            });
    }
});

<!-- Fin API -->
```

---

Gracias de antemano. Saludos

Comment: Hola, entiendo lo que intentas y aunque es una forma de evitar que un usuario registre más de un voto, hay una razón por lo cual ésto no sería lo más adecuado, ya que estarías creando una correlación entre 1 voto y 1 usuario. Esto violaría el principio de secreto del voto, ya que se podría establecer esa relación usando los datos correlacionados. Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo con @MauricioContreras. Esa consideración es MUY importante en este escenario; debe separarse el control de quién ya votó (un registro o planilla -una tabla-) con quienes hayan depositado su voto y otra tabla, sin ordenamiento ni asociación de ningún tipo, donde vaya la dirección de cada voto y un Id autonumérico o aleatorio o algo que no permita asociar un voto con un votante.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné así:

```
/* VOTAR */

routerApi.post('/:id/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.id) {

        Candidato.update({ _id: req.params.id }, { $inc: { votos: 1 } }, { safe: true },
            function(err, response) {
                if (err) return res.status(500).send(error);
                if (response) {
                    User.updateOne({ _id: req.session.userId }, { $set: { voto: true } }, { safe: true },
                        function(err, response) {
                            if (err) return res.status(500).send(error);
                            if (response) {
                                res.status(200).redirect('/resultados');

                                // Corroboro el proceso de voto
                                console.log('Voto exitoso!')
                                console.log('ID de sesion del votante: ', req.session.userId);
                            }

                        });
                } else {
                    res.status(500).send(new Error("No se pudo votar"));

                }
            });
    }
});
```

Tal vez, a alguien le sirva. Saludos

Comment: Hola, me alegra que lo hayas conseguido. Te invito a leer [answer]. Si bien tu respuesta puede ser válida, sería un poco mejor si agregas una explicación del proceso subyacente. Aunque el código tenga comentarios que deberían ser suficiente guía, siempre es preferible una explicación breve y concisa (o una extendida si fuese necesario) de cómo lograste solucionarlo y el porqué elegiste esta forma de hacerlo. Saludos